# \cite is not autocompleting in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

Overleaf is supposed to have the autocomplete feature of citations, according to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/270-in-line-rich-text-comments-and-multi-citation-auto-complete#.WE936k_QeV4) . But, it is not working for me. What did I wrong (or, is it restricted to paid version?)?

Comment: Why don't you ask OverLeaf? I mean, surely they are most likely to provide a definitive answer?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: @Dellu, it's not restricted to paid version, I have the free version and it works for me. Do you have a `.bib` file in your Project? And is this file loaded with `\bibliography` or `\addbibresource`? You have to do both these things for getting the autocomplete feature to work.

Comment: Also try refreshing the page? And check that you have no syntax errors in the .bib file (e.g. missing commas after a field)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I contacted the support: they suggested breaking down the library. Yes, it is working after splitting the library into two. I am posing the question here because others will learn from it: and, hey, Overleaf is nice service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some possible reasons the `\cite` autocomplete list isn't showing up on Overleaf:

- Try refreshing the browser page; sometimes it's a script not completely loading.
- There's a syntax error in the .bib (e.g. a missing comma after a field) that prevents the parser from reading all the keys correctly
- The .bib file is very, very large, so the parse can't read through it efficiently.

The last point happens to be the cause in this case; the two .bib files you're using is 1MB+ and 2.4MB+. If you split the .bib files into smaller chunks (<1MB per file), then refresh the page, the autocomplete suggestion list should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you LianTze: yah, you are right. Breaking up the library alleviated the problem. But, today, I learned that the true culprit is not the size of the library; it is a duplicate key.

Comment: ah, that's a good catch!

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I learned that the main culprit is a duplicate BibTex key. Two of my entries have identical BibTex key. That was annoying the parser in Overleaf.